# how to hide the stack trace(exception details) in server response to client in wcf

Tags: wcf

I have 6 wcf services , when client send request to service,  the server returns a stack trace when there is an exception which is a security concern.
Some method do have Faultexception , however , since they are returning the exception object, stack trace is showing up.  Now its is a tedious process to modify each and ever method, so is there any way we can show generic error message and not the detailed exception?
sample code:

````
            {
                throw new FaultException<ServiceBaseFaultContract>(new ServiceBaseFaultContract(102, string.Format("Error occured"), ex));
            }```
````

Answer (score 1):

If your WCF service is not hosted in IIS, either close the Exception details, or capture the detailed information of each exception and return it to the client. Normally, we should not expose the exception details to the client.Your can turn off this in config:

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
```

If the WCF service is hosted in IIS, we can return a custom error:

[image]

I added an exception with http status code 415:

[image]

This is a custom exception received by the client:

[image]

If no custom error is set, the client will receive a detailed error message:

[image]

**UPDATE**

We can interface IErrorHandler to configure global exceptions,here is a Demo:

```
 public class ExceptionHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception ex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void ProvideFault(Exception ex, MessageVersion version, ref Message msg)
        {
            string err = string.Format("error");
            var newEx = new FaultException(err);

            MessageFault msgFault = newEx.CreateMessageFault();
            msg = Message.CreateMessage(version, msgFault, newEx.Action);
        }

    }
```

We need to implement the IErrorHandler interface.

```
public class ExceptionBehaviourAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly Type _errorHandlerType;

    public ExceptionBehaviourAttribute(Type errorHandlerType)
    {
        _errorHandlerType = errorHandlerType;
    }

    

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription description,
    ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription description,
    ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
    Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
    BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription description,
    ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        var handler =
        (IErrorHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(_errorHandlerType);

        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase dispatcherBase in
        serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var channelDispatcher = dispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
            if (channelDispatcher != null)
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we need to add the implementation class of IErrorHandler to the behavior of the service.

[image]

Finally we apply it to the service.

[image]

I did not throw an exception in the ADD method, but I still get an exception when I call it from the client.

Comment: But when i send request to server using SoapUI,  lets say i pass invalid arguments to a method, like say passing a string for an integer etc, the server sends http response where we can see exception with the stack trace, modifying the method to return only exception message is one method, but i have 5 services each consisting of 100 methods, in this case its not feasible to do a code clean up for every method and it is a huge effort, so is there any way to handle like glonbal exception in MVC?